# PHP async packages running synchronous instead of async

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous

Okay i need to perform an api call and two db calls.. In total it takes about 43 seconds (synchronously). But the longest call takes 16 seconds, which then would be total time async.

It's my first time trying to perform something async in PHP, but i found some packages that looked like it was pretty straight forward. I tried following pacakges:

- guzzlehttp
- spartie
- vmx/laravel-async

The problem is that, no matter which package i use, it's perfoming the code synchronously.

I'm on rock bottom here, anyone who are experienced working with async packages that can point me in which direction i should look?

Using examples in their documentation, it's still running synchronously.
https://codebrisk.com/blog/run-your-laravel-app-code-asynchronously-with-laravel-async

```
use Async;

for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
    Async::run(function () use ($i) {
        sleep(1);

        return $i;
    });
}

var_dump(implode(', ', Async::wait()));

// Output value may be like:
// string(65) "5, 2, 1, 14, 4, 6, 7, 8, 19, 16, 12, 18, 13, 3, 10, 9, 11, 17, 15"
```

But my output would be 1, 2, 3, 4, ect..

I found some documentation saying that if ext-pcntl extension was not installed it would fallback to running synchronously. But as far as i can see, ext-pcntl are installed and enabled on my server.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#concurrent-requests

Comment: You probably have to use the batch run function or search in documentation if they provide a method which resolves multiple async functions, how you run now its synchronous way and not async

Comment: krisgjika laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#concurrent-requests this is only for requests, not for db calls as far as i can figure out :( 

VasoGamdelidze According to this documentation https://codebrisk.com/blog/run-your-laravel-app-code-asynchronously-with-laravel-async the code should be async and not synchronous